# What are the differences in these SQL closure table examples?

Tags: mysql, recursion, tree, hierarchical-data, transitive-closure-table

I am having some difficulty wrapping my mind around SQL closure tables, and would like some assistance in understanding some of the examples I have found.

Lets say I have a table called `sample_items` with the following hierarchical data:

```
id   name                   parent_id
1    'Root level item #1'   0
2    'Child of ID 1'        1
3    'Child of ID 2'        2
4    'Root level item #2'   0
```

The tree structure should effectively be this:

```
id
| - 1 
|   | - 2
|       | - 3
| - 4
```

For ease of querying trees (such as finding all of the descendants of a specific id), I have a table called `sample_items_closure` using [the method described by Bill Karwin in this excellent SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462). I also use an optional `path_length` column for querying the immediate child or parent when needed. If I understand this method correctly, my closure table data would look like this:

```
ancestor_id   descendant_id   path_length
1             1               0
2             2               0
1             2               1
3             3               0
2             3               1
1             3               2
4             4               0
```

Every row in `sample_items` now has an entry in the `sample_items_closure` table for both itself and all of it's ancestors. Everything makes sense so far.

While studying other closure table examples, however, [I came across one that adds an additional ancestor for each row](https://coderwall.com/p/lixing/closure-tables-for-browsing-trees-in-sql) that links to the root level (ancestor_id 0) and has a path length of 0. Using the same data I have above, this is what the closure table would look like:

```
ancestor_id   descendant_id   path_length
1             1               0
0             1               0
2             2               0
1             2               1
0             2               0
3             3               0
2             3               1
1             3               2
0             3               0
4             4               0
0             4               0
```

To give better context, here is a select query used on that site, modified to fit my examples:

```
SELECT `id`,`parent_id` FROM `sample_items` `items`
  JOIN `sample_items_closure` `closure`
  ON `items`.`id` = `closure`.`descendant_id`
  WHERE `closure`.`ancestor_id` = 2
```

I have two questions related to this method:

**Question #1:**

Why would an additional row be added linking each descendant to the root level (id 0)?

**Question #2:**

Why would path_length be 0 for these entries, instead of being the previous ancestor's path_length+1? For example:

```
ancestor_id   descendant_id   path_length
1             1               0
0             1               1
2             2               0
1             2               1
0             2               2
3             3               0
2             3               1
1             3               2
0             3               3
4             4               0
0             4               1
```

**Bonus Question**:
Why do some examples still include an adjacency list (the `parent_id` column for `sample_items` in my example) when the full structure of the tree is already expressed in the closure table?

Comment: I can't see where `0             3               0` comes from in your closure table. It's not in that second link you give. Maybe you misinterpreted it?

Comment: #A1: For the universality of the query. You can get full tree by `  WHERE `closure`.`ancestor_id` = 0` This example comes from times when there was no object-query-builder. #A2. length from 0 to 1 is 0 because is couple root elements.  #BQA: To get only part tree.

Comment: Regarding bonus question: this can be either a legacy model or a handy method to retrieve immediate parent without join on closure table

PS: Did you find the answers to questions 1 and 2?

Comment: It's been a while but I should revisit this topic and expand upon it further now. I'll need to take another look at my current closure table implementations to refresh my memory a bit before responding to some of the comments/answers here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CTE's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive). They are made for exactly those use cases and have many great examples, which are close to your case.